# Is there a way to change highlight color schema in LogBack

Tags: logback

In Logback, %highlight() is used to color the output. Is there any way to change the color schema for highlight()? I prefer the INFO level logs stay white instead of blue....

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>
            %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %highlight(%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n)
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```